# How to add user name to comment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When a User creates a comment. How can we add his name to it? I tried current_user but that obviously just state's the current user's name instead of the name of the person who made the comment.

In User model `has_many :comments, as: :commentable` in comment model `belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true` which in routes is broken down with `resources :users do resources :comments end`.

**views/comments/_comments.html.erb**

```
<div id="comments">
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
    <div class="comment">
        <%= current_user.name %>
        <%= simple_format comment.content %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

**comments controller**

```html
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :load_commentable
  before_action :set_comment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

 def index
  @comments = @commentable.comments
 end

 def new
  @comment = @commentable.comments.new
 end

 def create
  @comment = @commentable.comments.new(comment_params)
  if @comment.save
   @comment.create_activity :create, owner: current_user 
   redirect_to @commentable, notice: "comment created."
  else
   render :new
  end
 end

 def edit
  @comment = current_user.comments.find(params[:id])
 end

 def update
  @comment = current_user.comments.find(params[:id])
  if @comment.update_attributes(comment_params)
   redirect_to @commentable, notice: "Comment was updated."
  else
   render :edit
  end
 end

 def destroy
  @comment = current_user.comments.find(params[:id])
  @comment.destroy
  @comment.create_activity :destroy, owner: current_user
  redirect_to @commentable, notice: "comment destroyed."
 end

private
  def set_comment
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  end

 def load_commentable
  resource, id = request.path.split('/')[1, 2]
  @commentable = resource.singularize.classify.constantize.find(id)
 end

 def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:content, :commentable)
 end
end
```

I made showing various names in the activity feed work by creating a controller. Are there principles in here I could take to make it work because I've tried and failed.

```
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
 def index
 @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at desc").where(owner_id: current_user.following_ids, owner_type: "User")
 end
end
```

**users migrations**

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
create_table :users do |t|
  t.string   :name
  t.string   :email
  t.string   :provider
  t.string   :uid
  t.string   :oauth_token
  t.datetime :oauth_expires_at

  t.timestamps null: false
end
end
end
```

**comments migration**

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
create_table :comments do |t|
    t.text :content
    t.belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true

  t.timestamps null: false
end
add_index :comments, [:commentable_id, :commentable_type]
end
end
```

**valuations_controller**

```html
class ValuationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_valuation, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

  def index
    if params[:tag]
      @valuations = Valuation.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    else
      @valuations = Valuation.order('RANDOM()')
    end
  end

  def show
    @valuation = Valuation.find(params[:id])
    @commentable = @valuation
    @comments = @commentable.comments
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  def new
    @valuation = current_user.valuations.build
    @commentable = @valuation
    @comments = @commentable.comments
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @valuation = current_user.valuations.build(valuation_params)
    if @valuation.save
      redirect_to @valuation, notice: 'Value was successfully created'
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'pages/home'
  end
end

  def update
    if @valuation.update(valuation_params)
      redirect_to @valuation, notice: 'Value was successfully updated'
    else
      render action: 'edit'
  end
end

  def destroy
    @valuation.destroy
    redirect_to valuations_url
  end

private
    def set_valuation
      @valuation = Valuation.find(params[:id])
    end

    def correct_user
      @valuation = current_user.valuations.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to valuations_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this valuation" if @valuation.nil?
    end

    def valuation_params
      params.require(:valuation).permit(:name, :private_submit, :tag_list, :content, :commentable, :comment)
    end
end
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: How are you authenticating the use before they comment. You need to collect his details or authenticate via third party apis and get the information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have

#### User model:

```
class User
  has_many :comments
  ...
end
```

#### Comment model

```
class Comment
  belongs_to :user
  ...
end
```

#### Comment migration

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.text :content
      t.belongs_to :user, index: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

you can get the user's name of a comment by

```
@comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
@comment.user.name
```

**EDIT: If you want to work with polymorphic associations, edit your models like this**:

```
class User
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
  ...
end

class Comment
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
  ...
end
```

**EDIT: Insert Comments migration**

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.text :content
      t.references :commentable, polymorphic: true, index: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

**EDIT related to ValuationsController**

1. You are looking for the user who created a specific valuation comment. @valuation holds this comment. So you can get the user with `@valuation.commentable.user.name` - This assumes, that your Valuation sets the correct association to Comment model.
2. Delete  `@commentable = @valuation` and `@comments = @commentable.comments`. They are not wrong, but in that case it doesn't make any sense to hold variables with the same value.
3. In the 'show' action you've assigend @comment with Comment.new. Delete this line, because you are not creating new objects in the show action.
4. You've already assigned @valutation in the before_action at the top of your class with the same value. To prevent confusion, delete this additional assignment in the show action.

A clue for future debugging: If your code doesn't work as expected, try it running in the rails console. We've seen yesterday, that the code around `@comment.commentable.user.name` was correct. That showed me, that there must be something wrong in your controller.

### Final Solution

Add `<%= User.find(comment.user_id).name %>` to _comments.html.erb

Comment: I already have `def set_comment @comment = Comment.find(params[:id]) end`. If I use `@comment.user.name` in the view I get an error: `undefined method user for #<Comment:0x007ffe27b78e00>`. Thank you though!

Comment: How are your migrations of users and comments?

Comment: Try with ```owner``` instead of ```user```.

Comment: @Anthony: Did you set the references in your migration?

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com what he suggested is correct. How are `Comment` and `User` associated since that would be helpful in your question rather than the other code you have shown which is much less useful.

Comment: @klausinho I added migrations above. Do I need to add a reference to User? `has_many :comments, as: :commentable` isn't good enough?

Comment: @engineersmnky I'll show the association better. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks again Klausinho. I think you are on the right track. I tried `@comment.commentable` with `.name` `.owner` `.current_user` `.user` but they all gave me `undefined method for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Did you adjust your migrations? Take a look at my edited answer

Comment: Just one note: I really recommend to use the first solution. The corresponding code is more readable, i.e. `@comment.user.name` is more expressiv than `@comment.commentable.name`

Comment: Thank you Klausinho. With your update we are still given, `undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass`. hmmm. I would use your recommendation, but comments are being used for a variety of models. I got the code from http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association-revised?view=comments @klausinho

Comment: Have you tried this at rails console? What does 
`@comment = Comment.find(1)` and `@comment.commentable` return?

Comment: @klausinho `2.1.3 :001 > @comment = Comment.find(1)
  Comment Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
 => #<Comment id: 1, content: "Test 1", commentable_id: 1, commentable_type: "Valuation", created_at: "2015-04-03 18:18:37", updated_at: "2015-04-03 18:18:37">`

Comment: @klausinho `2.1.3 :002 > @comment.commentable
  Valuation Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "valuations".* FROM "valuations" WHERE "valuations"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
 => #<Valuation id: 1, name: "Be the change you wish to see in the world.", private: false, user_id: 1, created_at: "2015-04-03 18:18:30", updated_at: "2015-04-03 18:18:30">`

Comment: Anthony, could it be that you have filled your db with that example after my last comment? Your last result of  @comment.commentable is definitely not nil and must respond to `name`. But the result is not that what you want. What does `@comment.commentable.user.name` return?

Comment: @klausinho `2.1.3 :003 > @comment.commentable.user.name
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
 => "Anthony Galli"` but if I put it in the code I get `undefined method 'user' for nil:NilClass` And I put in your code before that comment.

Comment: Sorry, I did not meant the code but the values of valutations.

Hmm, at the console you get your wanted result. Where exactly do you want to retrieve the creating user name? In the show action?

Please update the post with the whole related controller.

Comment: Yea in the show action. valuations_controller added :) @klausinho

Comment: I would have thought this feature was built in because what's the point of comments if you don't know who is saying what.

Comment: Alright, I've edited my answer. The last days I was just looking at the CommentsController because you've never said a word about a ValuationsController and a Valuation model ;)

Comment: Yea @klausinho I should definitely spend more time getting comfortable with console. Unfortunately your newest edit isn't working errr sorry. I had looked at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19737034/rails-polymorphic-comments-undefined-method-user-name maybe you can see why his works, but ours isn't. I mimicked a lot of his code, except I changed member to user, but I was given `undefined user` still. With your edits I'm given `undefined method 'commentable'`. I know I need `@commentable = @valuation @comments = @commentable.comments`, just because every example I've seen has them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74504/discussion-between-klausinho-and-anthonygalli-com).

Comment: Okay @klausinho I'll be over there.