# How to get user name of Liker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

The example line in here didn't work. I tried 20 varieties of it.

**views/comments/_comments.html.erb**

```
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
  <%= User.find(comment.user_id).name %>    # Gives user name of commenter
  <%= simple_format comment.content %>
  <%= pluralize(comment.likes, 'like') %>
  <%= link_to content_tag(:span, '', class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up') + 
    ' Like it', like_comment_path(:id => comment.id), method: :post %>
  <%= User.find(like.user_id).name %>       # How to get user name of liker?
<% end %>
```

**comments_controller.rb**

```
def like
  @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  comment_like = current_user.comment_likes.build(comment: @comment)
  if comment_like.save
    @comment.increment!(:likes)
    @comment.create_activity :like
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    flash[:success] = 'Thanks for liking!'
  else
    flash[:error] = 'Two many likes'
  end  
    redirect_to(:back)
end
```

**comment_like.rb**

```
class CommentLike < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :comment
   belongs_to :user
   validates :user, uniqueness: { scope: :comment }
end
```

**comment.rb**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    include PublicActivity::Common
    # tracked except: :update,  owner: ->(controller, model) { controller && controller.current_user }
    has_many :comment_likes 
    has_many :likers, through: :comment_likes, class_name: 'User'
    belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: What's with the dislikes? I've been having a hard time with this question. Am I missing code?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I saw your question from a day or two ago and it appears you did not take the advice of people who gave you answers, as you still have `User.find(comment.user_id)` in your view code.

Comment: Thanks @MikeManfrin for the explanation. I said I'd get to it eventually :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A comment has many likes. So you are looking for the comment likers.

```
class Comment
  has_many :comment_likes
  has_many :likers, through: :comment_likes, class_name: 'User', source: :liker
end

class CommentLikers
  belongs_to :liker, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :user_id
  belongs_to :liked_comment, class_name: 'Comment', foreign_key: :comment_id
end

class User
  has_many :comment_likes
  has_many :liked_comments, through: :comment_likes, class_name: 'Comment', source: :liked_comment
end
```

Then in your views:

```
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
  <% comment.likers.each do |user| %>
    <%= user.name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**EDIT 1**

Your question is so well explained in the rails guides:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

But just to give you a short explanation:

You need to associate the comments through the comment likes to the users. To do you need to tell rails to look for the user in the table using the user_id.

That's what the `through: :comment_likes, class: 'User'` do.

**EDIT 2**

Check the source code to see more options:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many

Comment: Good try Jorge! Thank you! I got this though `undefined method 'each' for 2:Fixnum` for line `<% comment.likes.each do |user| %>`

Comment: Jorge you have a little error, in model `Comment` you have  `likers` but in the view you try `comment.likes` instead of `comment.likers` so @AnthonyGalli.com if you try the change maybe it works.

Comment: When I put `has_many :likers, through: :comment_likes` in comment.rb, user.rb & commentlike.rb we get: `undefined method 'klass' for nil:NilClass` despite making the changes @Aguardientico suggested for line `<% comment.likers.each do |user| %>`

Comment: @JorgedelosSantos I've been reading through your links. Thank you for them! Your code unfortunately raises errors: `Could not find the source association(s) "liker" or :likers in model CommentLike. Try 'has_many :likers, :through => :comment_likes, :source => <name>'. Is it one of comment or user?` If I then add code to comment_like.rb as I think is suggested, `has_many :likers, :through => :comment_likes, :source => 'Comment'` we get `undefined method 'klass' for nil:NilClass`. Maybe it's because the comments are polymorphic? I updated the question :)

Comment: @Aguardientico maybe you have any more suggestions on why it's not working? I've been at this a few hours and I don't see myself getting any closer.

Comment: Unfortunately this gives `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Valuations#show SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: comment_likes.liker_id: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "comment_likes" ON "users"."id" = "comment_likes"."liker_id" WHERE "comment_likes"."comment_id" = ?` @JorgedelosSantos

Comment: You know nothing about Rails, Associations, SQL and anything related. Which is bad. Because you seem to be expecting others to write your code just by asking here: "How can I?". Well sorry, no time for more help, create a nice github page and share your full code. Or learn enough rails to do challenging questions. The "has_many with foreign key" is no longer relevant.

Comment: I'm trying my best @JorgedelosSantos. I just wanted the right answer. I thought this was a good question other people would find useful. Thank you for your time.

Comment: It's a good question, but you are expecting the full code snippet. Sent you an email. Added another clue.

Answer (score 0):

1) If `like` variable declared in controller it should be global: `@like`

2) Don't use `User.find(comment.user_id).name` or `User.find(like.user_id).name`.

Use it like `comment.user.name`, `@like.user.name`

Comment: That gives: `undefined method 'user' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: And here is the long answer to why this is `<%= User.find(comment.user_id).name %>` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29353577/how-to-add-user-name-to-comment

Answer (score 0):

The short answer

In your controller, change

```
  comment_like = current_user.comment_likes.build(comment: @comment)
  if comment_like.save
```

with

```
  @comment_like = current_user.comment_likes.build(comment: @comment)
  if @comment_like.save
```

In your view, change

```
<%= User.find(like.user_id).name %>
```

with

```
<%= @comment_like.user.name %>
```

Comment: Thanks Aguardientico! I gave this a try, but got `undefined method 'user' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com I found my error, in your controller you are redirecting to `back`, can you put the action that `back` is calling?

Comment: Aguardientico `redirect_to(:back)` refreshes the page depending on whether it is valuations#show, habits#show, goals#show, quantifieds#show. I may move away from show though and allow users to like/comment directly on the activities_controller index.

Comment: I got you, I asked you about the action because in each action you should add code to get the `like (comment_like)` variable, but I guess, the better answer is to use Jorge de lo Santos's answer.